# RDFa chaining with about and resource

Tags: chaining, rel, rdfa

The W3C recommendation for RDFa Core 1.1 Second Edition gives examples for chaining: http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-core/#h3_s_chaining

Example 29:

```html
<div about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Albert_Einstein">
  <div rel="dbp-owl:residence">
    <span about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/German_Empire"></span>
    <span about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Switzerland"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why don't they use `resource` instead of `about` to state the object? like this:

```html
<div about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Albert_Einstein">
  <div rel="dbp-owl:residence">
    <span resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/German_Empire"></span>
    <span resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Switzerland"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or does chaining with `rel` and `resource` not work for some reason?

In the recommendation they say, that `about` is used to state a subject in RDF terminology and `resource` can be used for objects: http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-core/#h2_s_syntax

But here (in example 29) `about` is used to state the object IMO. What should I use now? `about` or `resource`?

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the two versions using [RDF translator](http://rdf-translator.appspot.com/) you'll see that the versions are semantically identical. However, IMHO, it is better to have a single `about=""` enhanced with one or more resources. Logically, `about=""` is similar to `skos:topConcept`. The related statements, identified with `resource=""`, add precision to the `topConcept`.